# Unable to write the same Java code in C++ because "cannot initialize class member here" ERROR

Tags: java, c++, linked-list, turbo-c++

I'm doing a C++ implementation of Singly Linked List that I've already done in Java. The Fraction of my Java code is as follows :

```
class Node
{
    int info;
    Node next;
    Node()
    {
        next=null;
    }
} 
class Op
{
    Node front= null;

    void display()
    {
        Node rear=front;
        if(rear==null)
            System.out.println("List is empty");
        else
        {
            while(rear!=null)
            {
                System.out.print("["+rear.info+"|"+rear.next+"]"+"--->");
                rear=rear.next;

            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

**next** stores the address of the next Node in the list,
 **front** points to the first node in the list and
 **rear** is used to sequentially travel the list.

Below is the C++ code that I'm trying to implement :

```
class Node
{
    public:
    int info;
    Node *next;
    Node()
    {
        next = NULL;
    }
};
class Op
{
    public:
    Node *front = NULL; //error line.
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using the Turbo C++ 3.0 compiler and the error it gives is :

> Cannot initialize a class member here

I'm aware that the above problem can be resolved if I use C++11 but unfortunately the code has to be in Turbo C++ 3.0.
The **front** has to be **NULL** in order to check if the list id empty or not.
How do I solve this issue?

Comment: See [this question about initializations in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15451840/4125191).

Answer (score 1):

try this :-

```
Class Op 
{
 public : Node *front;
 Op():front(NULL){};
};

void main()
{
    Op o  // constructor called.
    Op *op; // pointer - no constructor called.
    Op *op2 = new Op; // constructor called.

    cout << o.front; // NULL
    cout << op->front; // garbage value
    cout << op2->front; // NULL
}
```

Comment: I tried this inside main():
Op *op;
cout<<op->front;

Comment: and that returned an address instead of null, how do I check if it is null inside the if() condition?

Comment: I copy-pasted your code and the output for all the three cout statements are : 0x8f850000

Comment: The garbage value and the null values are same?

Answer (score 0):

have you call the header files?
Sometimes JAVA programmer forget to include the header files in C++.  :-P

I think the line :-

```
public * front = NULL;
```

should be :-

```
public : NODE *front = NULL;
```

Comment: That was a typo, my bad. That isn't the issue

Comment: Yes I've called all the header files needed

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it in C++:

```
class Op
{
public:
    Node *front;
    Op() : front(NULL) {}  // default constructor
};
```

Comment: I tried accessing **front** inside main() and it displayed an address. Is this supposed to return an address instead of a NULL value?

Comment: If the list is empty, then **front** must contain **NULL** but instead it has some address inside it. The **if()** condition will fail right?

Answer (score 0):

Initialize it in constructor:

```
Op() :
 front(NULL);
{}
```

Still it's interesting that it's not working in Turbo C++. g++ can handle it.