# Cannot initialize a class member?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, visual-studio-2015, initializer-list

In my notes that I am going through I came to this page where it shows

```
class Student{
public:
    Student()
    {
        age = 5; //Initialize age
    };
private:
    int age; // **Cannot initialized a class member**
    string name; // **Cannot initialized a class member**
 };
```

What does it mean that you can not initialize a class member? This is a topic about constructor initializer list. I have tested in VS using this code and it works fine.

```
class TestClass
{
    int number = 27; //The member is initialized without a problem.
public:
    TestClass();
    int getNumber(); // Return number
    ~TestClass();
};
```

I apologize if I am asking a stupid question but I am hoping to learn better by posting this question here.

Comment: Depending on when you took your notes, what compiler you were using, what standard you were using this may be a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15451840/why-cant-we-initialize-class-members-at-their-declaration

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks! That explain why. But now I have a bigger problem. I do not know whether in my exam paper which one should I write!

Comment: Is your class being taught to a particular standard?

Comment: http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#member-init

Comment: @NathanOliver Not sure about now. I failed this exam once. And its been over a year. Going to resit this paper on coming thursday. Probably going to get to my lecturer asap

Comment: @Student I would find out what standard they are using as things have changed.  If they don;t give you a standard to base your answer off then you may want to think about going somewhere else.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yeah but that is the cheapest college I can afford for programming lessons :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second example (initialising non-static class member at point of declaration) is permitted only in C++11 or later.

The first is valid before C++11, although it is often considered better to implement the constructor using an initialiser list rather than assigning it in the constructor body.

```
//  within your definition of class Student

Student() : age(5)
{
};
```

If you intend your code to work with older (pre-C++11) compilers you cannot initialise non-static members at the point of declaration.

If you intend your code to work only with C++11 (or more recent) compilers then both options are valid, and the choice comes down to coding style (i.e. it is subjective).

Answer (score 1):

Prior to c++ 11 you can't initialize a non static variable. You need to use getters and setters.

```
class Student{
public:
    Student()
    {
        age = 5; //Initialize age
    };
private:
    int age; // **Cannot initialized a class member**
    string name = "Hello"; // Invalid 
};
```

Comment: Yeah. Now I am even more confused on which I should use in my exam paper soon :(

Comment: Check your notes, better user getter and setter methods so you can be on safe side instead of initializing variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you are an Indian and class 12th student this answer is for you...

See code 1 is perfectly fine and will run fine according to all standards of c++. In code 2 you can only initialize static member at the time of declaration if you are using standard older than c++11

Now, what is generally taught in Indian school is standard older than c++11(c++03 I guess). But VS uses latest compiler and compiles code accordingly. Hence, your code runs on VS but is wrong according to book