# can we convert Audio (.mp3) to video (mp4) in android studio? how?

Tags: android-studio, audio, video, android-mediaplayer, converters

i am new in this and i am working on App of media player and recording app. in which i have shown song list of device in the listview and recording start / stop / play. Now i want to convert that .mp3 recorded file into .mp4 and one image will show on behalf of a video in that file. Help me to achive this i have no idea and i refer many links and i didnt find anything.

Comment: Re: the second sample, looking just at the code, what is the value of `temp` at the moment you assign `b=temp;` If you're answer is, "I don't know", you're in good company because neither does your program. It invokes *undefined behavior*

Comment: it will returning the value of temp variable because your assigning b=temp and then printing it the second logic is wrong.

Comment: TBH `int a=10` looks fine, even in the class. What's the smallest program that causes the error, what's the exact errror? Instead of asking 3 bad questions, each of which is missing a lot, please ask 1 good question.

Comment: It might help of you focus your post on one single question, with an accompanying [mcve].

Comment: You name a member function after your class??? If you want to write a constructor: these have no return values, i. e. you need to drop `void`. You might prefer the initialiser list against assignment: `swap() : a(10), b(20) {}`

Comment: *"\\cannot declare here"* - if you mean compiler complains and you cannot use *default initialisation*, maybe you are using an outdated compiler? Maybe you need to add appropriate compiler flags (e. g. GCC: one of `-std=c++11/14/17/0x/1y`, depending on version...).

Comment: can anybody help with this question?

Comment: @Drashti Add another question, you have edited the same question that you ask previously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this link for your first question:
[Why can't we initialize class members at their declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15451840/why-cant-we-initialize-class-members-at-their-declaration)

Usually constructor is use to initialize value to data variables of class.

For 2nd Question: 
If data member is not initialize after creation of object, It will contain garbage value. So initialize or assign suitable value to as per your need.

Check below code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class swap_values
 {   
    int a, b, temp;
    public:
        swap_values(){
            a=0;b=0;temp=0;
        }
        swap_values(int x, int y){
              a = x;
              b = y;
              temp = 0;
           }

        void swapped()       
        {
            temp = b;
            b=a;
            a=temp;
        }
        void print(){
         cout<<"a: "<<a<<" b: "<<b<<endl;
         }
 };

int main()
{  
   int x =10; int y = 20;
   swap_values obj(x, y);
   obj.print();
   obj.swapped();
   obj.print();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: can anybody help with this question?

Answer (score 0):

Everything can be done in better ways but just using your code this will work for you -

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Swap  {

    private:
        int a,b,temp;

    public:

        Swap()
        {
            a=10;
            b=20;
            temp=0;
        }

        void swapNums()
        {
            temp=a; a=b; b=temp;
            cout<<a<<" " <<b<<endl;
        }
};

int main() {

    Swap s;
    s.swapNums();

    return 0;
}
```

You can avoid using class name as some function name. You can instead use constructor without a return type where you can initialise the member variables. swap method looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

> i am not able to initialize my variable in class.
>
> ```
>  class swap
>  {
>       int a=10; \\cannot declare here
>       int b=20; \\ cannot declare here
>  }
> ```

Since C++11, this is fine, you can have [*default member initialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization).
The error is due to missing semicolon after `}`.

> why it has garbage value with b ??
>
> ```
> a=b;
> b=temp;
> temp=a;
> ```

Since `temp` was never initialized before assigning it to `b`, `temp` has an *indeterminate value*.
Any usage will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub#Uninitialized_scalar).

Here's a simple Swap `struct`:

```
 struct Swap
 {
     int a = 10; // default member initialization
     int b = 20; // default member initialization
     Swap(int a = 20, int b = 10): a(b), b(a) {}; // swap on initialization
                                                  // using member initializer list
 };

 Swap s;
 std::cout << s.a // 20
           << s.b // 10
           << std::endl;
```

In this example, default member initialization is "obsolete" / "redundant" due to [member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).

Comment: Suppose you should mention that now, with complete constructor, default initialisation just got redundant/obsolete...

Comment: can anybody help with this question?